# How to edit '.dat' files in python?

Tags: python, bash

So I'm doing some molecular dynamic simulations for my final year university project. 
I am new to coding and have been asked to convert some code from BASH to python. 
The BASH script essentially takes a number of data files: ...x.dat where x is the number of simulations run. I am looking at the distances between carbons (c1 & c10) and generating a histogram based on distance between these 2 carbons over 30nanoseconds. The first 10ns has to be removed from the data for reasons I won't go into. The BASH script looks like this:

```
!/bin/bash

# number of runs to process
x=1
int=1
X=6
# code (modify name of files if appropriate)
for x in `seq $x $int $X`; do
  sed '2,2501d' wt_atas_fpps_C1_C10_r$x.dat > wt_atas_fpps_c1_c10_af10_r$x.dat
  awk '{$1=$3=""; print $0}' wt_atas_fpps_c1_c10_af10_r$x.dat > tmp.dat
  sed '1d' tmp.dat > wt_atas_fpps_c1_c10_af10_onlydist_r$x.dat
  rm tmp.dat
  perl ./histogram.pl -i wt_atas_fpps_c1_c10_af10_onlydist_r$x.dat -o hist_wt_atas_fpps_c1_c10_af10_r$x.dat -min 2.0 -max 12 -col 1 -int 0.1 -freq
done
```

The data file looks like this:

```
#Frame       C1-C10-d         sdih
   1       4.5218      79.2201
   2       4.9504      78.0684
   3       4.5568     138.0529
   4       4.6582      65.7324
   5       4.4398     119.6567
   6       4.6302     105.3040
   7       5.5387     146.4703
   8       4.6112      90.8193
   9       5.0781     106.4628
  10       5.3428     139.9808
  11       4.4887     132.3399
  12       5.1901      95.9297
  13       4.7968     128.4568
  14       5.8146     100.8803
  15       5.3278     105.8811
```

Up to 7500 (so 7501 rows in total). I think the Bash script essentially removes rows 2-2501 to get rid of the first 10ns. It then removes the columns 1 & 3 to get only the distance column. The header is then removed by deleting the first row to have a file with only distances. A perl histogram script is then run to generate a histogram.

My question is how do I replicate this in python? I can't find an easy way to remove certain columns or rows for this kind of file .

Comment: .dat is just a flat ascii format, right? you could likely read that into a pandas DataFrame and easily manipulate the contents, and them dump back out to file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is very doable in python, but you should post your attempt and where you are stuck

Comment: BTW, the script is also quite complicated for the few things it has to do. seds and awks could be easily simplified to a single awk.